# How to reject negative numbers as parameters in the Argparse module

Tags: python-3.x, command-line-interface, argparse

I have a time parameter and it can be any number except negatives and zero

```
parser.add_argument("-t", "--time",
                    default=2, type=int,
                    help="Settings up the resolution time")
```

How can I use choices option correctly?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pass any conversion function as the `type=` arg of `add_argument`.  Use your own converstion function, which includes the extra checks.

```
def non_negative_int(x):
    i = int(x)
    if i < 0:
        raise ValueError('Negative values are not allowed')
    return i

parser.add_argument("-t", "--time",
                    default=2, type=non_negative_int,
                    help="Settings up the resolution time")
```